# Querying Multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to queries and learning it. I have two tables, Emp and EmpDetail. I use a query to select the Emp like

```
Select Id,Name,Date where Date >= trunc(sysdate)-10
```

And the EmpDetails have more fields but I just have to select few filelds like

```
Select act,rol,comp,rescd from EmpDetail
```

Now to select records from both the table like having some conditions

```
Select em.Id
     , em.Name
     , em.Date
     , ed.act
     , ed.rol
     , ed.comp
     , ed.rescd 
  from Emp em
     , EmpDetail ed 
 where em.Id = ed.rescd 
   and ed.rol = 'req' 
   and em.date != Null
```

So using Inner Join

```
Select Emp.Id,Emp.Name,Emp.Date,EmpDetail.act,EmpDetail.rol,EmpDetail.comp,EmpDetail.rescd from Emp INNER JOIN EmpDetail where Emp.Id=EmpDetail.rescd and EmpDetail.rol='req' and Emp.date!=Null
```

Am I doing it correct

Comment: You could use the `join `. `from Emp em join EmpDetails ed on em.Id=ed.rescd and ed.rol='req' and em.date!=Null`  It will genrate the same plan for both of them, But the joins makes it clear and understandable to read .

Comment: It shows there are various Join . Which should I use here?

Comment: SImple `Inner JOIN` would suffice. [Read from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)

Comment: Nothing (not even NULL) is equal (nor not equal) to NULL!

Comment: @Strawberry I dont get you. != (Not Equal To) doesnot work here? I have to select dates which are not NULL

Comment: This statement ->  `and em.date != Null` will always evaluate to NULL. I.e, it will never be true.

Comment: the table has Date record with mostly NULL in it only some has dates on it. I have select the records which doesnot have NULL values how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JOIN`.

```
SELECT e.Id, e.Name, e.Date, ed.act, ed.rol, ed.comp, ed.rescd
FROM Emp AS e 
INNER JOIN EmpDetails AS ed 
ON e.Id LIKE CONCAT(%, ed.rescd)
WHERE e.Date >= trunc(sysdate)-10
```

Comment: How can I truncate if there are leading zeros in the ed.rescd

Comment: No I am wondering if  having e.Id as 1234 and ed.rescd as 00000001234 this query will work right

Comment: Check updated answer, you can use `LIKE` and `WILDCARD %`. But this will work too if you have for example `010001234`, in this way no care what will be before `ed.rescd`

Comment: Or if you know that you have exactly 7 x 0 before number you can use `CONCAT(0000000, ed.rescd)` and in this way `=` instead of `LIKE`

Comment: @@Stanislovas Kalašnikovas . Is there any way to truncating the leading 0000000 in the ed.rescd while comparing instead of concatenating. Just curious